# Not able to verify digital signature in Pdf file

Tags: java, cryptography, itext, digital-signature, java-security

I have a digitally signed pdf file and I am trying to verify the signature in that. But Signature is not getting verified. Below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, Object> keyPair = new HashMap<>();
        String password = "123";

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12"); //, "BC");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/shivam/Documents/Projects/label-processor/src/main/resources/DigitalSignatureFile.pfx"), password.toCharArray());

        Enumeration<String> keyStoreAliasEnum = keyStore.aliases();
        String alias = null;
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        byte[] signature = null;
        while ( keyStoreAliasEnum.hasMoreElements() ) {
            alias = keyStoreAliasEnum.nextElement();
            if (password != null) {
                privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());

                X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
                publicKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
                signature = x509Certificate.getSignature();
                keyPair.put("Alias", alias);
                keyPair.put("PublicKey", publicKey);
                keyPair.put("PrivateKey", privateKey);
                keyPair.put("X509Certificate", x509Certificate);
            }
        }
        verify(publicKey, signature);
    }

    public static void verify(PublicKey publicKey, byte[] sigBytes) throws Exception {

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        FileInputStream datafis = new FileInputStream("/Users/shivam/Desktop/DigitallySignedFile.pdf");
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(datafis);
        sig.update(data);
        boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigBytes);
        System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
                new File("/Users/shivam/Documents/Projects/label-processor/src/main/resources/VerifiedFile.pdf"),
                data
        );
    }
```

Above program is giving "**Signature verifies: false**". And In **VerifiedFile.pdf** I am still seeing signature not verified. But when I am trying to verify in **Adobe Reader** it is verifying correctly.

I tried verifying with the help of **itext** library also. It is verifying signature But In pdf it still shows **signature not verified**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    byte[] pdfBytes = Files.readAllBytes(
            Paths.get("/Users/shivam/Desktop/DigitallySignedFile.pdf")
    );
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
    AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
    List<String> signatures = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
    boolean valid = false;
    if (!signatures.isEmpty()) {
        for (String signature : signatures) {
            if (acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(signature)) {
                PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = acroFields.verifySignature(signature);
                valid = pkcs7.verify();
                String reason = pkcs7.getReason();
                Calendar signedAt = pkcs7.getSignDate();
                X509Certificate x509Certificate = pkcs7.getSigningCertificate();
                Principal issuerDN = x509Certificate.getIssuerDN();
                Principal subjectDN = x509Certificate.getSubjectDN();
                logger.info("valid = {}, date = {}, reason = '{}', issuer = '{}', subject = '{}'",
                        valid, signedAt.getTime(), reason, issuerDN, subjectDN);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
            new File("/Users/shivam/Documents/Projects/label-processor/src/main/resources/VerifiedFile.pdf"),
            pdfBytes
    );
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please first of all share the PDF in question for analysis. Adobe Reader accepts some really broken signatures which a decent validator will reject...

Comment: Ah, but in your case your approach is simply wrong. You don't check the signature integrated in the PDF, you take the signature of some X.509 certificate and check whether that signature is a valid detached signature of the PDF. Which doesn't make sense. You should instead look for some PDF library that supports validation of integrated signatures. Like iText which you have tagged your question with but not used at all therein.

Comment: @mkl I tried with itext library also. It is verifying the signature But It is not reflecting anything on the pdf. After opening the pdf I am still getting "Signature not verified".

Comment: *'But It is not reflecting anything on the pdf.'* - What do you mean by that? *'After opening the pdf I am still getting "Signature not verified".'* - Opening in what program? Getting as what output of what action? If it's in a program with a GUI, screenshots might clarify. Also please share the PDF in question.